# Making a shadow block instead standard block using 'block' function

Tags: javascript, blockly

Is it possible to create shadow block using function block? 
Example:

```
return block(
    "text_trim", 
    func.lineno, 
    { "MODE": "BOTH" }, 
    { "TEXT": this.convert(func.value) }
);
```

Function call returns a standard block. Can I add additional parameters so that function return a shadow block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this trouble, but I'm not sure that is good decision.

Changes in block (added 'domToMutation' function):

```
/**
 * @this Blockly.Block
 */

domToMutation: function(xmlElement) {
    if(0 !== parseInt(xmlElement.getAttribute('shadow'), 10)) {
        this.setShadow(true);
    }
}
```

Changes in PythonToBlockly (added mutation **@shadow**):

```
return block('...', node.lineno, {
            'FLD_TYPE': strValue
        }, {}, {}, {
            '@shadow': 1
        });
```